Confusion about (closed) submanifolds of Stein manifolds
I'm starting to study Stein manifolds and I think I'm confused by something that is probably very elementary (which possibly highlights how little I truly understand about basic manifold theory in general). If $M$ is a $n$-dimensional Stein manifold, then one of its properties as part of an older definition of what it means to be Stein is:

For every $p \in M$, there exist holomorphic maps $f_1, \dots, f_n : M \to \mathbb{C}$ and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that $(f_1|_U, \dots, f_n|_U) : U \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a holomorphic chart.

It is then apparent that closed complex submanifolds $N$ of $M$ inherit this property, but I seemingly don't understand why that is the case. I know that what this means is that I should be able to find holomorphic maps defined on $N$ which would form a holomorphic chart on $N$, i.e. if $N$ is $k$-dimensional at $p \in N$, I need a holomorphic map $N \cap U \to \mathbb{C}^k$ that is biholomorphic onto its image, where $U$ is some open neighbourhood of $p$ in $M$. I'm struggling to see which maps I should choose that will satisfy this property.
For a concrete example, let's say that $M = \mathbb{C}^n$ is our Stein manifold and $N$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $M$. Then for $p \in N$, I can take the identity map $\text{id} : z \mapsto z$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and all of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as the open neighbourhood of $p$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\text{id}$ is the required holomorphic chart on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Since the restriction of $\text{id}$ to $N$ defines a holomorphic map on $N$, I would assume that there is a way to turn it into the required holomorphic chart on $N$, but I'm not sure how that can be done. Could I get an explanation on how to do this?
For completeness, my definition of a $k$-dimensional submanifold $N$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is that for every $p \in N$, there is a holomorphic coordinate system $(w_1, \dots, w_n) : U \to \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $N \cap U = \{z \in U : w_j(z) = 0 \text{ for } j > k\}$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Thanks in advance for the help!

Do you know the implicit function theorem in holomorphic setting?

@MoisheKohan I know the implicit function theorem in the holomorphic setting defined for maps on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$

Then think how you can use it in your setting. It might help if you start with the case $n=2, k=1$.  Also, it is a good exercise to prove that $N\subset M$ is a complex submanifold if and only if there exists a complex manifold $X$ and a holomorphic immersion $X\to M$ whose image is $N$ and which is a topological embedding. (The two questions are closely related.)

Just to note, in your proposed example the identity map is not a holomorphic chart: The submanifold $N$ has dimension $k$ but the identity map on $M$ furnishes $n > k$ holomorphic functions. Instead, at each point $p$ of $N$ we can select $k$ coordinate functions that do locally constitute a chart for $N$.

First consider $\mathbb C\times \{0\}\subset \mathbb C^2$. On the ambient space you have the holomorphic functions $f_1(z)=z_1$ and $f_2(z)=z_2$ providing a chart near $0$. To get a chart for the submanifold $\mathbb C\times \{0\}$ you want to throw away one of them and keep the other one. What's your choice? Clearly $f_1$, because $\partial_{z_1}f_2 =0$.
Also in general you want to select some of the functions and you can base your decision on which to keep by looking at the derivatives at a point.
Let $f_1,\dots, f_n\colon M\to \mathbb C$ be holomorphic functions that provide a chart near some point $p\in M$. This means that if we choose (possibly another) local chart $z_1,\dots,z_n$ near $p$, then the Jacobian
$$
(\partial_{z_j}f_k(p))_{j,k=1}^n\in \mathbb C^{n\times n}
$$
has full rank. If $N$ is a complex submanifold through $p$, we may assume that the local chart $z_1,\dots,z_n$ is adapted to $N$, meaning that $N\cap U = \{z_{k+1}=\dots=z_{n}=0\}$ on some neighbourhood, such that $z_1,\dots, z_k$ define chart of $N$. Consider the truncated Jacobian
$$
(\partial_{z_j}f_k(p))_{\substack{j=1,\dots,k\\k=1,\dots, n}} \in \mathbb C^{n\times k}.
$$
This still has maximal rank $k$, hence there is a $k\times k$-minor with non-vanishing determinant. Let's relabel the functions $f_1,\dots, f_n$ if necessary, such that we can assume this is true already for the left most $k\times k$-minor
$$
(\partial_{z_j}f_k(p))_{\substack{j=1,\dots,k\\k=1,\dots, k}} \in \mathbb C^{k\times k}.
$$
Then the restrictions $f_1|_{N},\dots, f_k|_N\colon N\to \mathbb C$ are globally defined holomorphic functions on $N$ and near $p$ they define a local coordinate chart.

Thanks for your answer! So with your full rank argument, is that applying an implicit function theorem adapted to complex manifolds?

If so, I think what I'm confused in this argument is why does a change of coordinates (locally) preserve the fact that $f_1, \dots, f_k$ defines a chart at $p \in N$. Wouldn't this change of coordinate, say $\varphi$, actually give that $f_j \circ \varphi$ is a local change of coordinate at $\varphi^{-1}(p)$? In which case the $f_j$ do not define a chart at $p$ on $N$, but near $\varphi^{-1}(p)$ instead?

The argument does not use any implicit function theorem.  You can rephrase the condition without charts, if that helps: Non-vanishing of the Jacobian $\det (\partial_{z_i}f_j(p))_{1\le i,j \le n}$ with respect to any chart is equivalent to the $n$-form $df_1\wedge\dots \wedge d f_n$ being non-trivial at $p$.

After giving it some more thought, I think (or rather, I hope) I understand what's going on here. Is it because the rank of the Jacobian is independent of the choice of chart used to calculate it? As in, it doesn't matter whether we have a chart adapted to $N$ or not, the Jacobian will still have full rank at $p$. And then the conclusion follows from applying the inverse function theorem to guarantee a biholomorphic map. Is this correct?

I agree with both statements.

Ah great! Thanks again for giving some time to explain away my confusion.
